# Can you pass Generic type <T> to specflow steps?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cucumber, specflow

When binding the specflow tests, passing in strings, ints, json files is made easy by specflow however in the good practice of dry, can you pass in the generic type in the specflow steps?

e.g.

```
Scenario
When I call the URL with the RequestObject and Type <url> <request> <type>
The response shall equal <response>

|url|request|type                 |
|xyn|abc    |customObjectc#object |

[When(@"When I call the URL with the RequestObject and Type (.*)(.*)(.*)")]
public void WhenIBlablablabla<T>(string url, string request){}
```

Where `<T>` is the type being passed in, or something similar? I want to generalise my specflow as much as possible in the good practice of dry.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with minimal code repetition:

```
public void WhenIBlablablabla(string url, string request, Type type)
{
    // Do stuff
}

[When(@"When I call the URL with the RequestObject and Type (.*)(.*)(.*)")]
public void WhenICallTheURLWithTheRequestObjectAndType(string url, string request, string type)
{
    Type systemType = Type.GetType(type);

    WhenIBlablablabla(url, request, systemType);
}
```

Note that this solution does not allow you to pass generics as type parameters. You could use class reflection to inspect the methods of the current class to see if they accept the arguments and generic types based on the `systemType` variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use generics in the steps. When SpecFlow converts the parameters from the step in the feature to the parameters in the step binding, it is using the type information of the method parameters.
So the step binding method defines which type you get, not the content in the feature file.

Did you looked at Step Argument Conversion?
See http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Step-Argument-Conversions/

SpecFlow has default ones (they are the ones that are used for int, float, ...) and you can add your own ones.